# porting this code from tensorflow 1 to tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to port a code I found on one of the answer here at stackoverflow.com:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[3,3])

cond1 = tf.where(x > 10, x - 10, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond2 = tf.where(x < 4, x + 60, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond3 = tf.where(tf.logical_and(x >= 4, x <= 10), x, tf.zeros_like(x))
y = cond1 + cond2 + cond3

sample = [[10, 15, 25], [1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 10]]

print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: sample}))
```

So far, I have done:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=[3,3], dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

cond1 = tf.where(x > 10, x - 10, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond2 = tf.where(x < 4, x + 60, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond3 = tf.where(tf.logical_and(x >= 4, x <= 10), x, tf.zeros_like(x))
y = cond1 + cond2 + cond3

sample = [[10, 15, 25], [1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 10]]
```

But I can not find a way to print the result, since I can not do print(f(sample), as suggested by the porting guide.

Answer (score 0):

First create a model using,

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
model = Model(x, y)
```

then do,

```
res = model.predict(sample)
print(res)
```

`res` will be a numpy array.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions,k but got array with shape (3,3)

Comment: Thanks, turned out that shape has to be [3,] and not [3,3]